# What "upstairs" is Earl referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mule

In *The Mule (2018)*, after having lunch at Midwest, Earl suddenly bumps into
the Sheriff. He gives him two cans of caramelized corn:

> Earl: I went to a charity and I got this caramelized corn. And it is
> really terrific stuff.
>
> Sheriff: We can't accept this kind of stuff.
>
> Earl: Oh, you'll be
> doing me a great favor, if you would. I've got diabetes. I can't have
> it. They'd love it down at the station. And **the gals upstairs**, they'll love it, too.

What "upstairs" is Earl referring to?

Comment: From the context I'd assume he means the women working in the admin and typing pool upstairs at the (police?) station